# ROSSerial Arduino Arrays

Tags: ros, arduino, rosseral-arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm trying to use Rosserial Arduino to process some data from a low cost laser rangefinder. Over the course of a scan I try to add the data to an array of float in arduino:

```
float snd_distance = getDistance(servo_pos);
distance_array[servo_pos] = snd_distance;
```

Then I have a function which populates the message:

```
void populateMessage(float distances[145]){  
 //Set up frame data
  scanData.header.frame_id = "1";
  scanData.header.seq = scanData.header.seq++;
  scanData.header.stamp = nh.now();
  scanData.angle_min = 0.0;
  scanData.angle_max = 2.53072742;
  scanData.angle_increment = 0.0174532925; 
  scanData.range_min = 0;
  scanData.range_max = 40;  
  for(int i = 0; i <= 144; i++){
    scanData.ranges[i] = distances[i];
  }
  pub_scan.publish(&scanData);
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

However, there seems to be a problem copying the values of distances over to scanData.ranges. I see no errors during compilation, however execution locks up at that step and I seem unable to get past it. Has anyone seen this before? Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203529/rosserial-arduino-arrays/) by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on ROS Answers with karma: 593 on 2015-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few things jump out immediately:

```
scanData.header.seq = scanData.header.seq++;
```

Won't do what you expect (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

> for(int i = 0; i <= 144; i++){
> scanData.ranges[i] = distances[i];   }

You can't just write into an array like this (http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations#Arrays). You either need to allocate the array, and then move the data, or just set the array pointer to the appropriate destination:

```
scanData.ranges = &distances;
```

Don't forget to set the size as well:

```
scanData.ranges_length = 145;
```

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on 2015-02-21**:
Thanks for the tips. Didn't realize the ranges_length was a field I could write to looking at the message definition for laser scan. Suppose its implicit to all these arrays?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-02-21**:
Yep. In roscpp those wouldn't be arrays either, they would be std::vectors. But rosserial API is different than roscpp.